# wso2is saml sso login fails after 1256 patch

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 Identity Server installed (SP1 included) and I was doing some integration tests with Liferay. I was able to do saml sso login without any problem (with included attributes), but then I installed the critical patch 1256 and it doesn't let me to sign on anymore.
Here's what the log says:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-28 12:16:22,774] ERROR     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.assertion.DefaultSAMLAssertionBuilder} -  Error when reading claim values for generating SAML Response {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.assertion.DefaultSAMLAssertionBuilder}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-28 12:16:22,775] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Error processing the authentication request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor}org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error while building the saml assertion
```

I was trying to figure out what could change between patches. When I delete all requested claims or deactivate the option " Include Attributes in the Response Always" it has no problem at all, but it doesn't work for me that way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the `Subject Claim URI`?  By default it is not select...  If this can be an bug in WSO2IS with above patch. I also see this error when i selecte the email address as the  `Subject Claim URI`.  There is public [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3272) as well.

Comment: yes I changed it, I need to use email address as subject claim indeed.

Comment: It is bug in patch 1256, there are some new patches, can try with them  http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/    If not, just remove the patch 1256.. or else check with WSO2.. whether they can offer new patch for above bug..

Comment: Thanks. I removed the patch until I find I a solution.